# Google service account open p12 for "access token"

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-analytics-api

I have this code (see end of question) and all I have to do is put in my access token, the thing is I've downloaded the p12 file and whenever I try to open it, I just get some Microsoft certificate program that doesn't tell me the stuff I need, how do I go about getting inside this p12 file to get the access token that its asking for?

Thanks.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
 <title>Google Charts</title>
     <script>
        (function(w,d,s,g,js,fs){
        g=w.gapi||(w.gapi={});g.analytics={q:[],ready:function(f){this.q.push(f);}};
        js=d.createElement(s);fs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        js.src='https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js';
        fs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fs);js.onload=function(){g.load('analytics');};
    }(window,document,'script'));
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

    <script>

    gapi.analytics.ready(function() {
    var ACCESS_TOKEN = '???'; // obtained from your service account

    gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
        serverAuth: {
            access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN
        }
    });

    var data = new gapi.analytics.report.Data({
    query:  {
    ids: 'ga:????????',
    metrics: 'ga:users,ga:sessions,ga:bounceRate',
    'start-date': '30daysAgo',
    'end-date': 'yesterday',
    'output': 'dataTable',
        }
    });
    data.execute();

    data.on('success', function(response) {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(response.dataTable);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({fractionDigits: 2});

    formatter.format(data, 1);

    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('test'));
    table.draw(data);
    });

    });
    google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['table']});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(table);

    </script>

</head>

<body>          
                <div>
                    <div id="embed-api-auth-container"></div>
                    <div id="test"></div>     
                </div>        
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't try and use a service account with the embed API.  Use normal oauth 2 as shown in the documentation  [Embeded API Getting started](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/devguide)

```
gapi.analytics.ready(function() {    
  // Step 3: Authorize the user.    
  var CLIENT_ID = 'Insert your client ID here';    
  gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    container: 'auth-button',
    clientid: CLIENT_ID,
  });    
  // Step 4: Create the view selector.    
  var viewSelector = new gapi.analytics.ViewSelector({
    container: 'view-selector'
  });
```

If you must use a service account I suggest you drop the embedded API and use a scripting language like PHP directly with the [reporting API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference).

Comment: Hey, the documentation also specifies  a server version here: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/component-reference spesifically in the "serverAuth.access_token" and further down provides the code to do this i just need to find out how to get the access token, i got the info from P12 file which has a public and private key, these don't seam to be what i'm after far to long for the token.

Thanks.

Comment: Embeded api is JavaScript it won't work with a service account